# what is traditional additive models and the differences between these models and machine learning models?

Tags: machine-learning, model

I read a SCI(PMID: 32437368) in the paper it said "Current stroke risk assessment tools presume the impact of risk factors is linear and cumulative. However, both novel risk factors and their interplay influencing stroke incidence are difficult to reveal using traditional additive models."I want to know what is traditional additive models?The difference between these models and machine learning models？Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional additive models are more based on nonparametric approaches where they are more prone to multicollinearity and overfitting issues.

Comment: In my opinion, I think traditional additive models are more parametric approaches, such as logistic. Can you provide a few specific model names as you suggested? Thank you